# React testing library conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

How I can conditional make test in testing library when have:
Rendering Loading component Skeleton is working but don't know how to mock useState?

```
const TextComponent = ({text}: WidgetProps): ReactElement => {

  const [calculatedData, setCalculatedData] = useState(false)
 useEffect(() => {
    if (text) {
      setCalculatedData(true)
    }
  }, [])

  if (!calculatedData) return <Skeleton className="skeleton-profile" />
  return (
     <div data-testid="displayText">
       {text}
     </div>
)
}
```

***Component.test.tsx***

```
describe('basic render', () => {
  test('render skeleton', async () => {
    const {container} = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <TextComponent text={text} />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    )
    expect(container.getElementsByClassName('skeleton-profile').length).toBe(1)
  })
  test('render Component', async () => {
    const {getByTestId} = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <TextComponent text={text} />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    )
    expect(getByTestId('displayText')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

The Error I get is:
`TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="displayText"]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your component needs a local state to handle this logic. Your `text` prop is essentially the same as your `calculatedData` state. It would make more sense to remove the local state and `useEffect`, and use the prop as the condition directly, which will make it easier to test as well:

```
const TextComponent = ({text}: WidgetProps): ReactElement => {

  return text ? (
    <div data-testid="displayText">{text}</div>
  ) : (
     <Skeleton className="skeleton-profile" />
  )
}
```

Then in your test file you just need to write 2 test cases:

- it renders the text if the text is truthy (pass a truthy value as the `text` prop to the component in your test)
- it renders the skeleton component when the text is falsy (pass a falsy value as the `text` prop to the component in your test)